# Feature selection priority (Matlab)

Tags: classification, feature-selection

I classify some data based on libsvm classifier. I used K-fold technique to evaluate the performance. Is this correct that I use Feature Selection technique in K-fold loop? I wrote a matlab code, I am feeling the priority of FS is wrong and it should be removed from this loop.
Please answer me. Thanks

```
for i=1:NumKfold 

   train_data=train{i}(:,1:end-1);
   train_p_target=train{i}(:,end);
   test_data=test{i}(:,1:end-1);
   test_target=test{i}(:,end);

    %======================Selecting Best Features=======================
     ------Feature Selection Based on Evolutionally Algorithm----

      ind0=output; % The index of best features

     str= '-c 1 -g 2 -b 1';
     svmStruct = svmtrain(train_p_target, train_data(:,ind0) , str);
     [predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values] = svmpredict(test_target,          
     C=confusionmat(test_target,predicted_label);
     acc_Selected_LibSvm(i)=sum(diag(C))/sum(C(:)); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No! You must select feature in out of K-fold loop. In fact, first select subset of feature by your Evolutionary Algorithm and then evaluate this subset. For evaluate any subset, pass this selected subset too your classifier and return average of accuracy on the k fold of your data. for example, if k = 10, your classifier run 10 time and average of this 10 run accuracy is fitness of input subset.